# Flutter And SocketIo: How to use socket_io_client in Flutter in the best way?

Tags: flutter, websocket, socket.io, flutter-dependencies

I am using `socket_io_client` for my project. But I am facing a serious problem. When I am listening for an event in my view-model class it is not triggering properly. I have tried many ways but is not able to come to a solution. But in `socket_io_client` 's documentaion, in their example, all of their event listener function is in the `main.dart` file. Like this:

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

main() {
  // Dart client
  IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000');
  socket.onConnect((_) {
    print('connect');
    socket.emit('msg', 'test');
  });
  socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
  socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
  socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));
}
```

and this too if I want to use it as a stream,

```
//STEP2: Add this function in main function in main.dart file and add incoming data to the stream
void connectAndListen(){
  IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000',
      OptionBuilder()
       .setTransports(['websocket']).build());

    socket.onConnect((_) {
     print('connect');
     socket.emit('msg', 'test');
    });

    //When an event recieved from server, data is added to the stream
    socket.on('event', (data) => streamSocket.addResponse);
    socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));

}
```

So, as far as I can understand, to listen event properly, it must be in a function which is continuously running like `main()` function.

When my socket code is running in the main function, all the events are triggering properly, but I also need to pass that socket and stream to my `provider` from the `main()` function.

So, I have come to an approach similar to this below, but to me, I don't think it is the best way to do so. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? or what is the best way to implement `socket_io_client` in flutter?

Or is the practice to ok to send data from `main()` function to `MyApp()`?

my `main.dart` file containing socket code:

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

void main() {
  DataStream dataStream = DataStream();
  IO.Socket socketio = listenToSocket(streamSink: dataStream.addResponse);

  runApp(MyApp(
    socketio: socketio,
    documentStream: dataStream.getResponse,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.socketio, required this.documentStream})
      : super(key: key);

  final IO.Socket socketio;
  final Stream documentStream;

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<DataStore>(
          create: (context) => DataStore(
            socketio: socketio,
            documentStream: documentStream,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataStream {
  final _socketResponse = StreamController();

  StreamSink get addResponse => _socketResponse.sink;

  Stream get getResponse => _socketResponse.stream;

  void dispose() {
    _socketResponse.close();
  }
}

IO.Socket listenToSocket({required StreamSink streamSink}) {
  List documentList = [];

  IO.Socket _socketio = IO.io(
    ('ws://192.168.0.106:3000/data'),
    <String, dynamic>{
      "transports": ["websocket"],
      "autoConnect": false,
    },
  );

  _socketio.connect();

  _socketio.onConnect((_) {
    print('connected');
    _socketio.emit('get-data', 0);
  });

  _socketio.on('new-object', (object) {
    print('triggering new-object from addDocument');

    documentList.add(Document.fromJson(object));
    streamSink.add(documentList);
  });

  _socketio.on('deleted-object', (id) {
    print('triggering delete-data from deleteDocument');
    documentList.removeWhere((document) => document.id == id);
    streamSink.add(documentList);
  });

  _socketio.on('recent-data', (data) {
    print('triggering recent-data from getDocument');
    documentList.clear();

    documentList.addAll(
        data.map((documentJson) => Document.fromJson(documentJson)).toList());
    streamSink.add(documentList);
  });

  return _socketio;
}
```